# How to 'npm run build' on the server regularly

Tags: javascript, next.js

My webpage doesn't update contents too often, and users don't necessarily need to get the latest contents. So most pages are generated at server side, and serves static pages.

However, there will be database update. That should be visible on the web page. So I want how to 'npm run build' regularly while my server serves stably. How do I do that?

Comment: What triggers that update in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would want to have a [corn job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on your sever to trigger your `npm run build` regularly.

If that doesn't suites you, another approach is to take this totally to cloud, have your server expose an endpoint with appropriate security credentials, such as `https://yourdomain.com/rebuild`. Every time this endpoint is hit, it triggers your rebuild.

On the other hand, have a cloud based "cron-like" service (e.g. [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/) or [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) ) to trigger this endpoint with your customised schedule.

If your server is deployed via a [CI/CD](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/principles/continuous-integration-vs-delivery-vs-deployment) approach, depending on your CI/CD provider (e.g. Github Actions), you can also set the scheduler on the provider side to regularly rebuild & redeploy your server app. With Github Actions as example, it supports [scheduler time based action triggers](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events-schedule).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking cron-job might be enough, but wasn't sure if there is a more standard and safe way. I will experiment cron job, then try Github Actions, that looks like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind for "regular" tasks that will be simple and won't require much setup is a corn job. You can add 'npm run build'(obliviously pointing to the right directory) to crontab with any schedule you want. Here's [a link with samples](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/) on how to setup cron.

But as you need to build your app and even run DB updates, it will be much safer and better to use CI solution. There are hundreds of them but my advice is to use [Buddy](https://buddy.works/pricing). It has a free plan and super easy to work with. 
With Buddy you can set up a pipeline that will SSH in your server and do the job. Or you can set up pipelines that will do all the actions at Buddy CI and then upload compiled files to the server.

Also, if we'd know what exactly 'npm run build' does, it will be easier to point for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Sorry, npm run build in nextjs does 'next build', which builds production application... You gave some good suggestions. thanks!